# What is the output of fully connected layer in CNN?

Tags: neural-network, caffe, conv-neural-network

For example, in Caffe, one should define num_output in an Inner Product (Fully Connected) layer. What is the meaning of this output number?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Consider fully connect layer as a simple matrix-matrix multiplication of `1xN` and `NxM` to produce a result of dimension `1xM`.

Let us consider that we pass a data of dimension say `56x56x3` as the input of a fully connected layer. Let the dimension of the weight be unknown `NxM`. Consider, we set `num_ouput = 4096`.

For computing these data, the fully connected layer reshapes the input data of dimension `56x56x3` as `1xN`, `1x(56x56x3) = 1x9408`.

Thus,

> N = 9408
>
> M=num_output=4096

In effect we end up doing a `(1x9408)matrix - (9408x4096) matrix` multiplication.

If the num_output value was changed to say `100`, it would end up doing `(1x9408)matrix - (9408x100) matrix` multiplication.

Thus increasing the `num_ouput` value will increase the number of weight parameters that the model has to learn.

Comment: I feel like you might be able to answer this question as well. It would be very appreciated. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40483458/caffe-reshape-upsample-fully-connected-layer)